# How can I configure prettier to NOT wrap the short version of the React.Fragment Tag?

Tags: reactjs

I like to do this:

const iAmVariable = <>{componentA}{componentB}</>

But prettier seems to want to turn this into something like:

```
const iAmVariable = (
    <>
      {componentA}{componentB}
    </>
)
```

This seems like wasted white space to me. If I used the actual class name React.Fragment okay, it's probably a big snippet, but if I'm using shorthand it's for a reason I would think.

How do I solve this, why shouldn't I and/or why I am wrong?

Comment: I am not aware of a fix directly towards this tag, but you can increase your workspace in general by increasing the amount of "max characters" Prettier is trying to fit into one line. Head over to `Settings > Prettier > Print Width`. Increasing this value will make Prettier trying to fit your code withing bigger width than now, possibly removing most (or every) of these.

Comment: Proposed solution doesn't seem to work, it didn't wrap because of width restriction but format. It also added the brackets. There has to be a way to do a one liner, otherwise what's the point off the short version of <React.Fragment>, why does <> exist, 2 chars on a line? This just seems like silly prettier not accounting for react or jsx.